# discord.py on channel create

Tags: python, discord.py

is there an event in discord.py that fires when someone creates a text/voice channel?

I would like the bot to understand when a channel is created so that it can release logs with

```
@bot.event
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are 2 events:

```py
@bot.event
async def on_guild_channel_create(channel):
    ...

@bot.event
async def on_private_channel_create(channel):  # called when a DM channel is created
    ...
```

#### References:

- [`on_guild_channel_create`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.on_guild_channel_create)
- [`on_private_channel_create`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.on_private_channel_create)

Comment: oh okok tankyou